# Rails where_exists combined with counting attributes of double-deep associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Filter` object that has_many `RelevanceLabels` associated with it. The `RelevanceLabel` belongs to an `Article`.

I am trying to do an ugly query: I want to find all `Filters` that have at least 10 `RelevanceLabels` where each `RelevanceLabel`'s `Article` does not have a `nil` `token_vector`.

I am currently using the `where_exists` gem, which makes the first part easy:

`streams_with_labels = Filter.where_exists(:relevance_labels)`

But then I'm still resorting to ugliness in loops:

```ruby
    stream = Filter.find(filter_id)

    labels = stream.relevance_labels

    return if labels.length < 10

    labels_with_tokens = labels.reject { |label| label.article.token_vector.nil? }

    return if labels_with_tokens.length < 10

    ...
```

I'm sure there's some chaining-fu that's just escaping me, but I'm not even sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you probably want to do here is just GROUP around `filters.id` and add a [HAVING](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL)) clause to add a condition for each group:

```
class Filter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relevance_labels 
  has_many :articles, through: :relevance_labels 

  def self.with_articles(n = 10)
    joins(:articles)
      .group(:id) # filters.id
      .where.not(articles: { token_vector: nil })
      .having(
        Article.arel_table[Arel.star].count.gte(n)
      )
  end
end
```

`Article.arel_table[Arel.star].count.gte(n)` is a more portable way of writing `having("COUNT(articles.*) >= ?", ?)`.